# Setting jQuery Timeout on a div containing Flash

Tags: flash, html, hide, settimeout

So, I need to remove a div once the flash has finished playing. I am using this so far (the first function is to show the flash div on hover, the 2nd to remove it.):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".showFlash").hover(function () {
          $("#flash").show("fast");
        });

    setTimeout(function() {
$('#flash').fadeOut('fast');}, 3000); // 
      });
```

It works fine the first time around. Though when I activate the flash again by hovering over the .showFlash element again - it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use timeout. Keep it simple

```
$(".showFlash").mouseenter(function () {
      $("#flash").show("fast").delay(3000).fadeOut('fast');
    });
```

Also I think you want to run this when mouse enters the .showFlash, not on hover (that triggers the event on enter and on exit)

Comment: Thanks Hose, I have tried your code but the "flash" div didn't fade away.

Comment: Works for me. Which browser and version you are using?

Comment: FF and V10... Don't think that's the problem though. Must be a conflict somewhere if it is working for you and not for me. Thanks for the help anyway...